# map.get(key) returning true instead of value

Tags: java

This is my first time asking on this site, so hopefully I didn't mess up any of the formatting. Anyway, I am having some trouble with getting the value from a key/ value pair from a map.
I initially pair the key (1 of possibly many substrings of String "word") with an abstract HashSet to hold "word"
However, when I try to print out the value paired with the key, I was expecting it to return the set. I receive "true" instead.
Any advice as to how I would print out the set of words? Do I have to make the set non-abstract for this to work?

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
/**
 * Method that is used to load a file containing a list of words
 *
 * @param fileName the name of the file containing words
 *                 either is .txt or .csv format
 */
@Override
public void initialize(String fileName) {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    String word;

    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            word = scan.next();

            for (int i = 0; i <= word.length(); i++) {
                wordMap.putIfAbsent(word.substring(0, i), new HashSet<>().add(word));

                System.out.println(wordMap.get(word.substring(0, i)));
                }
            }
        } catch(IOException e){
          //Exception handling stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that what you are actually adding to your map is the return from `add` which is a boolean. You aren't actually adding the set to your map.

Comment: I'm sorry, i forgot to mention "wordMap" is the HashMap im using to store the key value pairs: private Map wordMap = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();

Comment: You should show us the declaration of `wordMap`, which could be wrong.  But one part of the answer will involve removing that `HashSet` that you're creating, and just writing `wordMap.putIfAbsent(word.substring(0,i), word);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are trying to do new Hashset, it is returning boolean,it gives compilation error itself. You can trying doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= word.length(); i++) {
            HashSet<String> hs=new HashSet<>();
            hs.add(word);
            wordMap.putIfAbsent(word.substring(0, i), hs);
           // wordMap.putIfAbsent(word.substring(0, i), new HashSet<>().add(word));

            System.out.println(wordMap.get(word.substring(0, i)));
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E)) for `HashSet.add`:

> public boolean add(E e)
>
> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present. More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if this set contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)). If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false.

So in other words, `new HashSet<>().add(word)` is always the boolean `true` and that's what you're adding.

To create a new HashSet with one element in one expression, you can use `new HashSet<>(Collections.singleton(word))`

Comment: `Set.of(word)` might make more sense

Comment: Maybe. I assumed the set was to be modified, otherwise you could just add `word` itself

Comment: I meant `Set.of` as a replacement for `Collections.singleton`.

Answer (score 0):

Your map should be declared as:

```
Map<String,Set<String>> wordMap = new HashMap<>();
```

And then inside your loop:

```
String key = word.subString(0, i);
wordMap.putIfAbsent(key, new HashSet<>());
wordMap.get(key).add(word);
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice! However, when I try and do "wordMap.get(key).add(word);" it does not allow me to call the add() method

Comment: to clarify, it shows me methods such as equals(), notify(), notifyAll(). add() does not show up in the possible method calls.

Comment: @Robertkussmann you must have declared your map incorrectly. I'll show how to do it in the answer.